# "Would" vs. "will"?

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs, will-would, would

Are both of these sentences correct?

> I will go to the dance if I find somebody to go with me.
>
> I would go to the dance if I find somebody to go with me.

If so, does that mean "would" and "will" are interchangeable?

Answer (score 2):

Sentence 1 is a first conditional sentence, and it's correct.

Sentence 2, however, isn't correct. It's a second conditional sentence. So, it should be "I would go to the dance if I **found** somebody to go with me"

"Would" and "will" are not interchangeable in this case.

Comment: alternatively "I would go if I were able to find somebody to go with me"